# How do I get Rails 4 to serialize ActiveModel JSON with a nested root on a custom serializer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, active-model-serializers, activemodel

In Rails 3 my app serialized ActiveModel objects with the name of the model as the root, like:

```
{
  "car": {
    "id":29,
    "make":"Kia",
    "model":"Optima" }
}
```

Which was configured in:

```
#config/initializers/wrap_parameters.rb

ActiveSupport.on_load(:active_record) do
  self.include_root_in_json = true
end
```

I've kept the initializer setting include_root_in_json to true but it won't serialize with the model as the root of the JSON anymore when I have a custom serializer class:

```
#app/serializers/car_serializer.rb

class CarSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :make, :model
end
```

It's serializing like:

```
{
  "id":29,
  "make":"Kia",
  "model":"Optima"
}
```

I'd like it to serialize with the root named, but need the custom serializer to remove some sensitive fields from being serialized.

How do I accomplish what was the Rails 3 default behavior in Rails 4 so I can keep API backwards compatibility?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By removing the custom serializer class I was able to get the root node of the JSON to be the model name. To accomplish the exclusion of sensitive fields on the model from serializing into JSON I used the `except` clause when rendering

```
# app/controllers/car_controller.rb

respond_to do |format|
  format.html # new.html.erb
  format.json { render json: @order, except: [:sensitive_field_1, :sensitive_field_2] }
end
```

See the [Rails 4.0 docs](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.0/) -> ActiveModel -> Serializers -> JSON.